# Customize Bar button Item in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I am very new to coding and I have been watching a numerous youtube videos on how to customize (adding my own image) to the bar button item on a toolbar and none of the ways seem to be working.

Could someone please help or point me to the right direction?

Or should I just create a button instead and add the image and "command" to that?

Thank you!

[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SRQw.png)

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you want? Are you trying to link up a bar button item to do something, or having trouble arranging/moving them around?

Comment: lWhat do you mean by *customize*? Please be more specific.

Comment: What I meant by customizing is to add/replace the bar button items with my own images on the toolbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to add an image to a `UIBarButtonItem`:

```
// Create toolbar
let toolbar = UIToolbar()
toolbar.sizeToFit()

// My button with an image
let button = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "myImageName"), style: .done, target: self, action: nil) // Add a selector if you want an action when it is clicked

// Create toolbar using items
toolbar.items = [button]
```

Comment: Success!! Thank you so much!